# Wrong code for randomised print images

Tags: python, image, random

For a specific experience, I need to capture images very often (like a time lapse) and I want to send some of them to a printer from time to time.
So the idea was to download images from the camera to a folder (first step). Then to ask the code to make a random choice of one of these images and to send it to a printer in a random lapse of time (means not immediatly).(Step2)
And then send the image to an other folder to avoid to print it twice.(step3)
Am I clear ?

Well I must say I'm not so good so a friend of mine help. Here is our code, but for the moment it doesn't work and I don't understand why.
Could someone put us on the right track ? Please.

```
import os
import sys
from random import shuffle, randint
import time
import shutil

def checkDirectory(path):
    listExt = ('.jpg', '.JPG')
    listFiles = os.listdir(path)
    listImages = []

    for f in listFiles:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if ext in listExt:
            myPath = os.path.join(path, f)
            listImages.append(myPath)

    return listImages

def printImage(imageFile):
    command = "lpr {}".format(imageFile)
    os.system(command)

def printImages(path, pathDst):
    listFiles = shuffle(checkDirectory(path))
    print(listFiles)
    if listFiles:
        for f in listFiles:
            t = randint(60, 180)
            time.sleep(t)
            printImage(f)
            shutil.move(f, pathDst)

printImages(r"/Users/Aym/Desktop/eden/", r"/Users/Aym/Desktop/eden2/")
```

Comment: Hint: the return value of `shuffle` is `None`.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by '*for the moment it doesn't work*'? What is the output of `print(listFiles)`? What does the printer do?

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle` is used to change the order of a `list`, not to pick random elements from it.

Instead, use `random.choice`.

```
import random

# ... 

def printImages(path, pathDst):
    image_files = checkDirectory(path)
    if image_files:
        t = randint(60, 180)
        time.sleep(t)
        image_for_print = random.choice(image_files)
        printImage(image_for_print)
        shutil.move(image_for_print, pathDst)
```

Then, you'll want to repeat that so that you send an image "from time to time":

```
 while True:
     printImages(r"/Users/Aym/Desktop/eden/", r"/Users/Aym/Desktop/eden2/")
```

Comment: (thanks very much but =) image_for_print = random.choice(image_files)
NameError: global name 'random' is not defined

Comment: @NocNockie Don't forget the first line, you need to `import random`.

Comment: Oh I thought it was ok with [code]from random[/code]

Comment: @NocNockie `from random import choice` imports `choice`. `import random` imports `random`. If you use the former, then you should do `choice(image_files)`. If you use the latter, then it's  indeed `random.choice(image_files)`.